# why my python codes generate a runtime error

Tags: python, runtime

Python beginner, trying to solve the following question:

"Implement a class Class with the following attributes and methods:

A public attribute students which is a array of Student instances.
A constructor with a parameter n, which is the total number of students in this class. The constructor should create n Student instances and initialized with student id from 0 ~ n-1"

My codes:

```
class Class:

    def __init__(self, students):
        self.students = students

    def consID(self):
        n = len(self.students)
        if n > 0: 
            stu_id = [i for i in range(n)]
            return stu_id
        else:
            return False
```

Got a "runtime error" while testing sample student list and couldn't figure out why. Would appreciate your help!

Comment: What is the runtime error specifically?

Comment: "a runtime error" tells us nothing useful. Please always include _exact_ error messages, with traceback, when posting here. See [ask].

Comment: Also your code as it is here does not raise any error... There is just a class definition. In order to help you we will need a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

From the instructions I guess you want something like this

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id

class Class:
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.students = []
    for i in range(n):
      self.students.append(Student(i))

c1 = Class(3)
c2 = Class(8)
```

**Testing**

```
for student in c1.students:
  print(student.id)
```

**output**

```
0
1
2
```

```
for student in c2.students:
  print(student.id)
```

**output**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  After reading your code, I think I did not fully understand the instruction in the beginning. Appreciate it!

Comment: I'm glad I could help